# How to get a dialog to populate on all forms in orbeon

Tags: orbeon

I've got the following dialog that I can populate and use if I put it directly into the form. However, I want to put this on all forms without having to put the code into every form. I've saved the dialog into it's own separate email-dialog.xml file and I can call it using the 2nd snippet that is set inside of the properties-local.xml. The dialog shows up as a very tiny box with nothing inside except for the label "EMAIL ADDRESS" at the top where you drag the box. I can't figure out how to get the stuff inside to populate. I've recently updated to the latest version of Orbeon 2020.1.2.2021. Any help or direction would be appreciated.

```xml
<xxf:dialog     

xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
xmlns:xh="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:xxf="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms"
xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
xmlns:fr="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-runner"

id="my-dialog-id" 
appearance="full" 
level="modal" 
close="true" 
draggable="true"
visible="false">
<xf:label>EMAIL ADDRESS</xf:label>
    <xf:input id="textBoxDialog-control" bind="textBoxDialog-bind">
    <xf:label ref="$form-resources/textBoxDialog/label"/>
    <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/textBoxDialog/hint"/>
    <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
</xf:input>
<xf:trigger id="btnDialogBox-control" bind="btnDialogBox-bind">
    <xf:label ref="$form-resources/btnDialogBox/label"/>
    <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/btnDialogBox/hint"/>
    <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
    <!-- send email function-->
    <xf:action event="DOMActivate" type="xpath">
        fr:run-process('oxf.fr.detail.process', 'email')
    </xf:action>
</xf:trigger>
</xxf:dialog>
```

```xml
<property
   as="xs:string"  
   name="oxf.fr.detail.dialogs.custom.*.*"
   value="oxf:/forms/resources/email-dialog.xml"/>
   

<property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.fr.detail.process.send.*.*">
xf:show(dialog="my-dialog-id")
</property>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you have, in every form, a field named `textBoxDialog`, which you want to be populated with the value that users enter in the textfield shown inside the dialog you're showing when users click on the *Send* button. I would suggest that you make two changes to the code of your dialog:

1. In your `xf:input`, remove the `id`, or you might get a duplicate id error since you also have a control with the id `textBoxDialog-control` in every form.
2. For the button inside the dialog, don't reference the label of a control `btnDialogBox` inside the form, but instead puts the label in the code of the dialog.

With those changes, the dialog looks as follows:

[image]

And this is the modified version of your code:

```xml
<xxf:dialog
        xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
        xmlns:xh="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:xxf="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms"
        xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
        xmlns:fr="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-runner"

        id="my-dialog-id"
        appearance="full"
        level="modal"
        close="true"
        draggable="true"
        visible="false">
    <xf:label>EMAIL ADDRESS</xf:label>
    <xf:input bind="textBoxDialog-bind">
        <xf:label ref="$form-resources/textBoxDialog/label"/>
        <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/textBoxDialog/hint"/>
        <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
    </xf:input>
    <xf:trigger>
        <xf:label>Send</xf:label>
        <!-- send email function-->
        <xf:action event="DOMActivate" type="xpath">
            fr:run-process('oxf.fr.detail.process', 'email')
        </xf:action>
    </xf:trigger>
</xxf:dialog>
```

Comment: This is helpful. I'm still learning my way around Orbeon. One thing I'm stuck on is how can I get the input from the textBoxDialog and put it into the property that sends the email? I currently have this property:

`<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.email.to.TEST.TESTING" value="need to link the email here from dialog"   />`

Comment: This input field that you have in the dialog is "bound" to the same element as the corresponding input field you have in the form. It is in the Control Settings dialog for that text field that you tell Form Builder that the value of this input field is to be used as the recipient of your emails, by checking the following checkbox: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1UrY.png. You'll let me know if this works for you!

Comment: Oh! I thought I needed to link it in the properties for some reason. I removed that line and added `class="fr-email-recipient` to my textBoxDialog field in the dialog and it is working! Thank you for your help!

Comment: Perfect @Jolly9642, I am glad this did the trick; and you would use a property in your `properties-local.xml` if you wanted the recipient(s) email address(es) to be always the same (which could for instance be the case for a form where the email is sent to a person in charge of processing the data that is submitted).